# Is it worth creating 2 separate Laravel projects?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm planning to create an application with Laravel 5.8 that's going to be visited heavily by people and therefore speed is a priority for me.

I will create a frontend - where people are being redirected to a page - which needs to be as fast as possible - and a backend where I can see the statistics - which doesn't need to be as fast but will be robust.

So I was planning to create 2 separate Laravel projects, one for the frontend and one for the backend.

The reason I'm thinking this way is I don't want the backend files, etc to be slowing down the entire frontend by loading in unnecessary files, packages, routes, etc.

Am I thinking correctly and if speed is my priority, should I separate these 2 projects?

Comment: Check the "Laravel-boilerplate" project. It has 2 separated worlds (front and backend) in one project. They don't share files and stuff, they use their own route groups, middlewares, assets, etc. You don't need to create 2 projects.

Comment: What is the frontend technology? You may serve the frontend with node server (Angular / Reach / VueJS) and the backend would serve only an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason I'm thinking this way is I don't want the backend files, etc to be slowing down the entire frontend by loading in unnecessary files, packages, routes, etc.

They don't.

Laravel only loads (via the Composer auto-loader) most classes when they're used. If your code (controller, view, etc.) doesn't call `App\Foo` anywhere for a particular request, `App\Foo` isn't loaded.

If this is your reason for all the extra complexity of two different codebases, don't do it.